# Updatating a (Bulma) progress bar in real-time

Tags: javascript, progress, bulma

I am using Bulma and Javascript, trying to update a Progress Bar in Real-Time. I know how to do an indeterminate bar (keeps moving backward and forwards) and one where the bar starts moving when an event happens (eg, button pushed) but it then just moves forward on whatever timed basis has been programmed. I want my bar to move based on the actual task (reading records from a database, manipulating them, and saving the result) progress. If I chose to do all 17,000 records in one go it is likely to take 80-150 minutes, which is why I want a progress bar to show what is happening. I have provided below what I have so far.

Should my function update_progress_bar work (it doesn't)? Assuming that I have actually changed the progress bar value, how do I make that change the parameter in the web browser?

Many thanks in advance if you are able to point me in the right direction.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <title>My Title</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css"> </head> 
<body> <section class="hero is-primary is-fullheight"> 
<div class="hero-body"> 
<div class="container"> 
<div class="box has-text-centered has-text-weight-bold has-text-link is-size-2"> 
My Title 
</div> 
<div class="columns is-5-table is-4-desktop is-3-widescreen"> 
<div class = "column"> 
<label class = "label">Progress</label> 
<progress class="progress" value="20" max="100" id="myprogressBar">0</progress> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</section> 
<script type='text/javascript'> 
function update_progress_bar() { 
var element = document.getElementById("myprogressBar"); 
var current_value = element.value; 
element.value = current_value++; } 
</script> 
</body> 
</html> 
<?php for ($i=1; $i <=100; $i +10) { // do stuff update_progress_bar();}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want this code to update progress bar in the browser in real-time based on current task status.

I see several possible solutions:

1. The easiest.
   Just reload page programmatically every N seconds (like it is done in Jenkins)
2. Use `fetch` API (long polling or just using simple intervals) and get current status from some additional endpoint.
3. Use WebSockets. But only if you already use them in your project. If you don't - better use `fetch` API.

P.S. I don't know PHP. So this is solutions from point of view of JS dev.